# Determining support for SVG in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to devise a way to display an SVG image when rendering is supported and a png in the fallback case. I would like to do this on the server side for performance reasons because both are image formats are generated dynamically.

Is there a way to use the Page.Request.Browser to determine if SVG is supported?

Comment: I would hardcode for Ff, IE, and Chrome the minimal version that supports svg, and fall back on png for the rest. That will solve 95% of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up hardcoding the browser version after finding this [table](http://caniuse.com/svg). The versioning support is pretty straightforward so I just made a case statement.  Based on the table everything else should support SVG (at least partially). I don't need to support "Android Browser" so I left it out.

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser;

switch (browser.Browser)
{
  case "Firefox":
  case "Mozilla":
  {
    return browser.MajorVersion >= 3;
  }
  case "IE":
  case "IEMobile":
  {
    return browser.MajorVersion >= 9;
  }
  default:
  {
     return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you were looking for but I remember that [Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/) has support for that

```
bool Modernizr.svg
```

Your  could point to an action with this bool in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You could code separate partial pages one with the PNG image and one with SVG.
And in the client you could detect the support and make a get request to one of the partial pages and place it in the DOM.